# How can I change mouse cursor while it hovers over the map in Oracle Mapviewer

Tags: oracle-dbms

I'm using Oracle Mapviewer. I want to switch mouse pointer from default to crosshair when user enters "Interactive mode". I'm developing in GWT and tried do do something like this:

```
public static void setCursorCrosshair() {
    removeCursorStyles();
    getMapWidget().addStyleName("cursorCrosshair");
}
```

But it changes mouse pointer only in few parts of map, it looks like it omits map tiles and change cursor to crosshair on FOI's that I've added just before.
How can I make it to display crosshair over the whole map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured this out.
I had to grab all children nodes of mapWidget with name "img" and having string "gettile" in "src" attribute, then change theirs style as well as in case of MapWidget.
This way you can change stylesheet only for the map and map tiles and leave other images alone (such as map zoom bar, navigator, scale line, ect...).

XDOM is a class from Sencha GXT, but you can use anything other to find and iterate through nodes.

```
NodeList<Element> elements = XDOM.getElementById("mapViewWidget").getElementsByTagName("img");
    for (int i = 0; i < elements.getLength(); i++) {
        if (elements.getItem(i).getAttribute("src").indexOf("gettile") != -1)
            elements.getItem(i).addClassName(style);
    }
```